# How could I mute all notifications in Microsoft Teams on macOS 10.15.6?

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft

Microsoft bypasses the standard notifications mechanism in macOS: there is nothing in System Preferences -> Notifications to control both the sounds and the incessant popups.

Has anybody found away around this lack of utility?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Teams preferences (⌘ + ,) and toggle notifications preview and sound:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_teams-mso_o365b/turn-off-notification-sound-on-microsoft-teams/40aa9ebc-5746-46a7-b413-134d212c58ce

the off capability is buried in the ms teams app itself

[image]